# Firefox starts with last session. How can I change that?

Tags: 11.04, firefox

Firefox is curently starting with my last session. It's getting annoying. How can I change this so that it start with the home page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to *Edit > Preferences*. In the *General* tab you have the startup options near the top.

You can choose to either recover session or go to homepage, or a blank page.